# javascript combo box

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have used this function to call the following page depending on the chosen option.
The First **IF** will direct me to the **Monthly report** while the second **IF** will direct me to the **Daily report**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ActionDeterminator()
{
    var monthly = document.myform.duration.options[0].value;
    var daily = document.myform.duration.options[1].value;

    if (monthly == 0){
        document.myform.action = 'month.php';
    }
    if (daily == 1) {
         document.myform.action = 'day.php';
        }
}
</script>
```

I have also another function which will execute a job depending on the option. The first **IF** will convert my report to **excel doc** while the second **IF** will direct me to **view page to print**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function  ActionDeterminator()
 {

        if(document.myform.group[0].checked == true) {
           document.myform.action = 'excel.php';
           }
        if(document.myform.group[1].checked == true) {
           document.myform.action = 'view.php';
           }
        return true;
}

</script>
```

**The Problem:**

the problem is that it does not direct me to the correct page (whether monthly or daily)... it only directs me to view page or exporting to excel. Could anyone teach me the correct way to do this function?

**Also, I want to ask the correct javascript for combo box.**

Comment: @Todd How can I increase? Thanks.

Comment: Go back to other questions and select a winner - accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is get all the form elements into an array, loop, and evaluate for checked equals `true`

For example:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('group');
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems.item(i).checked == true) {
        break;
    }
}
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        //action = 'excel.php';
        break
    //case etc...
}
```